# What is this character?

Tags: translation

[image: unknown character]

I would like to know what this necklace means, thank you

Comment: Just guessing: 壽 (longevity).

Comment: Translation questions are off-topic for this site unless prior research effort has been indicated.

Comment: ←_← We may have to create a separate group or dictionary for short translation questions like this one.

Answer (score 2):

It's 寿（in simplified Chinese）: old age, long life; lifespan. It is used for expressing best wishes: wish people who wear it to have a good long life.

See [Ref](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%BD) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

shòu
**寿**
*longevity*

Example:

zhù nǐ jiànkānɡ chánɡshòu

**祝  你  健康      长寿**

May you stay healthy, live long.

Answer (score -1):

这是一个寿字，多用来祝福老年朋友们身体健康，比如：健康长寿，您今年高寿?

Answer (score -1):

it is 寿， usually it is a gift for older people to wish them have a good body and live longer